# In computer science, what is a server?

Tags: server

Should I imagine server as a physical device like router? Or is it just a program that is on a computer? I'm confused. Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: "apache" is a "web server". a "server" in general can be both a program or a physical device.

Comment: Answer is: depends. It can't get much better, as your question is way too broad. Think of a server as a system (physical device, or virtual machine) that provides some sort of "service" to "clients" which connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

A server is a computer that provides data to other computers. It may serve data to systems on a local area network (LAN) or a wide area network (WAN) over the Internet.

Many types of servers exist, including web servers, mail servers, and file servers. Each type runs software specific to the purpose of the server. For example, a Web server may run Apache HTTP Server or Microsoft IIS, which both provide access to websites over the Internet. A mail server may run a program like Exim or iMail, which provides SMTP services for sending and receiving email. A file server might use Samba or the operating system's built-in file sharing services to share files over a network.

[More about server](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvxLW0y4LOAhXHspQKHTpxBvIQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FServer_(computing)&usg=AFQjCNGVyVvUWpg77Yp9-Njdbg1Babdvfw&bvm=bv.127521224,d.dGo)